# App for tracking Home/Car/Personal Consumables

Tags: android, inventory

I'm searching for an app **for Android** that can track consumables spec and history, such as the following list:

- Upper Bathroom :: Lamp

  - Spec: CFL 14w
  - History:

    - Philips $1.00 (2018-02-03 to 2019-01-03 burnt out)
    - Osram $0.90 (2019-01-03 to 2019-08-25 burnt out)
    - Philips $1.20 (2019-08-25 to now)
- Suzuki :: Front Light

  - Spec: Halogen 55w
  - History:

    - SGP (2015-04-06 to 2018-05-07 burnt)
    - SGP $25 (2018-05-09 to 2019-07-21)
    - Osram H4 Nightbreaker Laser $35 (2019-07-21 to now)

And so on.

I've searched quite a bit and all apps I got are either too simple or too professional-oriented.

Is there an Android app that can keep track of consumables spec & history like I want above?

*Preferably* offline based (does not *need* always-on connection) but *preferably* can backup to the cloud (Google/Dropbox).

Comment: Hi. Please clarify if the specs/history is going to be entered yourself, or pulled automatically from a source.

Comment: @ZZ hi, sorry for not answering immediately. The specs/history will be entered by myself, not pulled from another source.

Comment: Hi. How did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use an android inventory app like one the following, even though not the initial use case:

- [Magic Home Inventory](https://apkpure.com/magic-home-inventory/net.twisterrob.inventory) - it enables boxes to be created using lists, which can then contain other items (Lists). So your specs can be put under each item in a "box". It works offline, and you can export manually to back-up but needs to copied to cloud.
- Also have a look at [Sortly](https://apkpure.com/sortly-inventory-simplified/com.sortly.mythings). You can probably use categories or folders to mimic Boxes.

You will find a few others on apkpure.com, but you will have to try out to see if they meet all your requirements.